# Need help pivot columns to rows SQL Server with count

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This is what I am trying to achieve in SQL Server but no luck.

I have table as below

```
ID  Start Dt    End Dt  Count
1   3/1/2016    6/1/2016    3
```

This is what I need, If Count column is 3 then I need to generate three rows

```
ID  Start Dt    End Dt  Count
1   3/1/2016    4/1/2016    1
1   4/1/2016    5/1/2016    1
1   5/1/2016    6/1/2016    1
```

Appreciate your help..

Comment: Please post your attempt so that we can help debug it.   What does "no luck" mean?   Did you get an error?

Comment: I think you are going to need a calendar table to generate those dates which don't appear in your original table.

Comment: Not really a PIVOT. You need a calendar table and join it with a BETWEEN start dt AND End Dt -> search stackoverflow for that, there are plenty of answers.

Comment: Hi Tab, thanks for your comment, I am not sure how do I achieve this, please give some suggestions so I can give a try.

Comment: Thank you guys, can you please give me examples.

Answer (score 1):

I use a UDF to create dynamic date ranges (see below).  I added another row in the sample data to illustrate the many-to-many.

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,StartDt Date,EndDate Date,Count int)
Insert into @Table values
(1,'2016-03-01','2016-06-01',3),
(2,'2016-02-01','2016-07-01',22)


Declare @MinDate Date,@MaxDate Date
Select @MinDate=min(StartDt),@MaxDate=max(EndDate) from @Table

Select ID,DateR1,DateR2,Count=cast((Count+0.0)/DateDiff(MM,StartDt,EndDate) as money)
  From @Table A
  Join (Select DateR1=RetVal,DateR2=DateAdd(MM,1,RetVal)  From [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@MinDate,@MaxDate,'MM',1)) B 
    on DateR1 Between StartDt and EndDate and DateR1<EndDate
```

Returns

```
ID  DateR1      DateR2      Count
1   2016-03-01  2016-04-01  1.00
1   2016-04-01  2016-05-01  1.00
1   2016-05-01  2016-06-01  1.00
2   2016-02-01  2016-03-01  4.40
2   2016-03-01  2016-04-01  4.40
2   2016-04-01  2016-05-01  4.40
2   2016-05-01  2016-06-01  4.40
2   2016-06-01  2016-07-01  4.40
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you. When I create function I am getting this error, Level 16, State 1, Procedure udf-Create-Range-Date, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "df.dateFrom" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure udf-Create-Range-Date, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "df.dateFrom" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure udf-Create-Range-Date, Line 14

Comment: It's your collation.. case sensitive.    Search and Replace all df. with DF.

Answer (score 0):

This is another method and it works.

```
declare @temp_table table (
        id int,
        start_date date,
        end_date date,
        count_no int
    )

    insert into @temp_table values (1,'3/1/2016','6/1/2016',3)

    select * from @temp_table
```

Above query will return your original results. And below query will return your expected results.

```
;with temp(count) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select count + 1
    from temp
    where count < (select count_no from @temp_table)
)
select tt.id, 
    convert(char, dateadd(month,count -1 , tt.start_date), 101) as start_date,
    convert(char, dateadd(month,count,tt.start_date ) , 101) as end_date, 
    count(*) as count

from temp as t cross join @temp_table as tt
group by tt.id,tt.start_date,t.count
```

HTH